# Whitesource: Keep two dependencies at the same version

Tags: whitesource

I have Whitesource set up to make PRs to my repo with version updates.

However, some times it makes PRs in which it updates one of two libraries that should remain at the same version.

For instance, I might have

```
quarkusPluginVersion=3.6.4
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.6.4
```

Then WS makes a PR in which it suggests updating one of them.

```
quarkusPluginVersion=3.6.4
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.6.5
```

As these libraries are meant to be kept at the same version, I was wondering if there is a way to configure Whitesource to only suggest upgrading them when they both have an available update to the same version?